# Start Android app with files on sdcard or somewhere in the filesystem

Tags: android, cordova, filesystems

I making an application with phonegap/cordova where I need to keep a lot of files up to date. Some files (mainly images) will need to be erased in time, and some new ones will get downloaded. The thing is, in Android, to manipulate those files, it seems I need to have them on the sdcard; so I copy the files the app starts with from my assets folder to the sdcard. It just seems like a waste of memory space.

Do you know if is there anyway I can start with the app having those files the app starts with already inside the sdcard? or at least somewhere I can delete them later?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do in a bit more detail?

Comment: Sure, I have an app with articles and images which need to be updated constantly. I don't wan't the app to depend on wireless conection to access content already viewed. So I need to be able to actualize some json files, download new images to the app, and delete the ones that aren't in use. I would like to have the original content of the app already on the package, so that it all doesn't have to be downloaded from a website the first time the app starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files that are delivered to the device as part of your APK will be stored in a form that cannot be modified by your application (other than by updating to a new version of the apk).

If you copy the files out of the APK into the private internal storage area or the external storage area, those copies can be modified, but the originals inside the apk will remain.

The most efficient solution may be to not put these files in your apk, but have your app instead download them separately on the first run, using whatever mechanism you wanted to use to change them in the future.

(Some people object to this feeling that such files are less secure against unauthorized use, but as the contents of an .apk are trivial to extract this is not a strong argument.  Needing to maintain a server to download from is a slightly more substantial objection.)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to store the files on the SD Card. Each app has its own internal storage that is not accessible by any other apps.  For more information see the official docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I read that, many many times, but I still don't get how to start with the app having files on Internal Storage so that I can delete them later. Also, I'm a little worried about devices that don't have a lot of Internal Memory, it recommends that I keep the apps Internal Storage under 1Mb; the files in the app will for sure be more than that. Wouldn't it be a problem?

Finally, the File Api of phonegap seems to default to sdcard in android with: LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT. Do you know how could I access Internal Storage with the Api?

Comment: Yeah, you just need to walk down the filesystem to get to / then you are at internal storage. Although it is a lot easier to do a "window. resolveLocalFileSystemURI()" passing in "/data/data/{package name}" and that will get you to the root of your apps internal storage.